# Is there a way to download an encoded file with window.open?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code to download a file on click:

```
    var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.data, null, "\t"));
    var dlAnchorElem = document.createElement('a');
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
    document.body.appendChild(dlAnchorElem);
    dlAnchorElem.click();
```

Due to some restrictions on the browsers I'm working with (inApp for android), this code does not work. So I'm thinking of a workaround..

I could use this code:

```
var url = "download.html";
var windowref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Cerrar,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

But since my content is dynamically generated (a dump of a json object), I can't pass it to download.html. Is there a way where window.open would take an encoded value in the URL parameter, so that when the new window opens, it would instantly download the file?

Comment: Can't you just set `window.location` to your data URI? Also, what are the restrictions, you mean the browser doesn't support the `download` attribute?

Comment: Yes, download is restricted on the inBrowser applications for cordova.